# Trying to print position of index value

Tags: python

`Code`

```
lst = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50] #We have list of products here


product = 1
index = 0

while index < len(lst):
    print("================================================================================")
    print("The current index position is :", index)
    product *= lst[index]
    print("The product holds the value   :", product, "is been multplied with value of :{}".format(lst[index]))
    index +=1
    print("================================================================================")
    print("\n\nPrinting the next while condtion")

print("\n\nWhile Condition has been completed since length condition {}".format(len(lst)), "has been met")
print("\nProduct is : {}".format(product))
```

`Output`

```
================================================================================
The current index position is : 0
The product holds the value   : 10 is been multplied with value of :10
================================================================================
Printing the next while condtion
================================================================================
The current index position is : 1
The product holds the value   : 200 is been multplied with value of :20
================================================================================
Printing the next while condtion
================================================================================
The current index position is : 2
The product holds the value   : 6000 is been multplied with value of :30
================================================================================
Printing the next while condtion
================================================================================
The current index position is : 3
The product holds the value   : 240000 is been multplied with value of :40
================================================================================
Printing the next while condtion
================================================================================
The current index position is : 4
The product holds the value   : 12000000 is been multplied with value of :50
================================================================================
Printing the next while condtion
While Condition has been completed since length condition 5 has been met
Product is : 12000000
```

I am expecting the product value should be assigned with value of 1 not 10, is there a way to assign the value of 10 and keep incrementing the same till while loop condition has been met.

Comment: Add sample output that you want

Comment: `lst[index]` starts at 10. You multiplied `product = 1` by 10, then 20, then 30, etc. I've edited the title since this is a logic issue, not syntax

Comment: Can you assist me with logic, where can i update the logic in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected output is not clear,

if you want the product=1 to be printed before all the multiplication:

```
Initial value of product is : 1

================================================================================
The current index position is : 0
The product holds the value   : 10 is been multplied with value of :10
================================================================================


Printing the next while condtion
================================================================================
The current index position is : 1
The product holds the value   : 200 is been multplied with value of :20
================================================================================


Printing the next while condtion
================================================================================
The current index position is : 2
The product holds the value   : 6000 is been multplied with value of :30
================================================================================


Printing the next while condtion
================================================================================
The current index position is : 3
The product holds the value   : 240000 is been multplied with value of :40
================================================================================


Printing the next while condtion
================================================================================
The current index position is : 4
The product holds the value   : 12000000 is been multplied with value of :50
================================================================================


Printing the next while condtion


While Condition has been completed since length condition 5 has been met

Product is : 12000000
```

you can add the print statement before the while loop

```
lst = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50] #We have list of products here


product = 1
index = 0

print(f'Initial value of product is : {product}\n')

while index < len(lst):
    print("================================================================================")
    print("The current index position is :", index)
    product *= lst[index]
    print("The product holds the value   :", product, "is been multplied with value of :{}".format(lst[index]))
    index +=1
    print("================================================================================")
    print("\n\nPrinting the next while condtion")

print("\n\nWhile Condition has been completed since length condition {}".format(len(lst)), "has been met")
print("\nProduct is : {}".format(product))
```

if you want the following output

```
================================================================================
The current index position is : 0
Current product value is: 1
Multiplying the current product with value 10
================================================================================


Printing the next while condtion
================================================================================
The current index position is : 1
Current product value is: 10
Multiplying the current product with value 20
================================================================================


Printing the next while condtion
================================================================================
The current index position is : 2
Current product value is: 200
Multiplying the current product with value 30
================================================================================


Printing the next while condtion
================================================================================
The current index position is : 3
Current product value is: 6000
Multiplying the current product with value 40
================================================================================


Printing the next while condtion
================================================================================
The current index position is : 4
Current product value is: 240000
Multiplying the current product with value 50
================================================================================


Printing the next while condtion


While Condition has been completed since length condition 5 has been met

Product is : 12000000
```

print before multiplying

```
lst = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50] #We have list of products here


product = 1
index = 0


while index < len(lst):
    print("================================================================================")
    print("The current index position is :", index)
    print(f'Current product value is: {product}')
    print(f'Multiplying the current product with value {lst[index]}')
    product *= lst[index]
    # print("The product holds the value   :", product, "is been multplied with value of :{}".format(lst[index]))
    index +=1
    print("================================================================================")
    print("\n\nPrinting the next while condtion")

print("\n\nWhile Condition has been completed since length condition {}".format(len(lst)), "has been met")
print("\nProduct is : {}".format(product))
```

PS. f-strings work only with higher versions of Python3